# need example of the interdependencies among the declarations and definitions of friend classes/ friend member functions (from C++ Primer)

Tags: class, declaration, friend

I'm new to C++ and currently reading C++ Primer and in Chapter7( which talks about the most basic class features) it talks about how important "careful structuring" is when we want to make member function friend of another class:

*"Making a member function a friend requires careful structuring of our programs to accommodate interdependencies among the declarations and definitions. In this example, we must order our program as follows:

- First, define the Window_mgr class, which declares, but cannot define, clear. Screen must be declared before clear can use the members of Screen.
- Next, define class Screen, including a friend declaration for clear.
- Finally, define clear, which can now refer to the members in Screen"*

My questions are:

1. When they talk about "order", do they mean the order which I write the code? I don't think the compiler cares if I am jumping back and forth between the header files/cpp files of the classes.
2. I plan to write the classes in the form of a header file for the structure and a separate cpp file for member functions/ related functions. Could you give me a concrete example of how to coordinates these steps?
3. A relevant question on classes: when I define class B which has a member function that returns type class A/ has a class A parameter, do I need to include class A's header file or do I just need to declare class A at the top of class B's header file like *class A;* and then just include classA.h in classB.cpp where I define the member function?

Thanks a lot!

Below are example code of Window_mgr and Screen from the book for context:

```
class Screen {
    friend void Window_mgr::clear(ScreenIndex);
    //...rest of the Screen class
};

class Window_mgr {
    public:
        using ScreenIndex = std::vector<Screen>::size_type;
        void clear(ScreenIndex);
    // rest of the class
};

void Window_mgr::clear(ScreenIndex i)
{
    // s is a reference to the Screen we want to clear
    Screen& s = screens[i];
    // reset the contents of that Screen to all blanks
    s.contents = string(s.height * s. width, ' ');
}
```

This post deems from not understanding friend/class in general...  so any detail can help. Thanks!